# how to make a jump in Unity2D using Animation Curve

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanna make agile jump in unity, and i did. The problem is that my animation curves ignore colliders. here is a video which showing it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hE4qI0cQ0SQ&ab_channel=Mis%60eNikolai. How do I make the jump work normally?

this is the jump implementation code

```
[SerializeField] private AnimationCurve _yAnimation;
[SerializeField] private float _jumpDuration = 3f;
[SerializeField] private float _jumpHeight = 4f;

 void Jump()
{
    StartCoroutine(JumpPositionCalculate());
}
private IEnumerator JumpPositionCalculate()
{
    float expiredSeconds = 0f;
    float progress = 0f;
    Vector3 startPosition = _tr.position;
    while (progress<1)
    {
        expiredSeconds+=Time.deltaTime;
        progress = expiredSeconds / _jumpDuration;
        _tr.position =new Vector3(_tr.position.x, 
        startPosition.y+_yAnimation.Evaluate(progress)* _jumpHeight);   
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think collisions are ignored only when you are jumping at a super high speed (Which doesn't seem to be the case here) or if you are dealing with physics outside of FixedUpdate (Which could be a case here).
So whatever you are using to jump, if you are applying force or velocity, then do it inside a fixed update, if you are changing position, then change Rigidbody position instead of changing transform but again do it inside Fixed Update.